# auto login with Cubian (debian with mate)

Tags: debian, login, autologin, cubieboard, cubian

How do I automatically log a user in using Cubian? I have tried removing the default users password but it still promotes to enter a username at the login screen.

I've tried editing the /etc/inittab to the following but with no success:

```
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f cubie tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Cubian, but i'm using Slim (so as Cubian as i read in the official site) to autologin Arch (in my mame cabinet).

I'm using the default_user option (i didn't get it if you don't want to use that) but to make it work I also needed to configure .xinitrc in the default_user homedir.

From my slim.conf configuration:

```
login_cmd           exec /bin/bash -login ~/.xinitrc %session

[...]

# default user, leave blank or remove this line
# for avoid pre-loading the username.
default_user        charlie

[...]

# Automatically login the default user (without entering
# the password. Set to "yes" to enable this feature
auto_login          yes
```

And my .xinitrc:

```
#!/bin/sh

[...]

exec xmonad&
exec wahcade
```

In your case I presume would be:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec mate-session
```

I hope i understood your question. Comment me something if I'm mistaken or something is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Marcs is right.  I just tried based on these instructions:
https://github.com/cubieplayer/Cubian/issues/323

The only difference from what Marcs said was the default user for Cubian was Simone.  Just change that to cubie in addition to setting auto_login yes :)